# keras model.fit() fed with initializable iterator of tf.Dataset object

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using the tf.keras API to build my CNN model with the use of the tf.Dataset API to create a input pipeline for my model. The mnist dataset from the `tf.keras.datasets` is used for testing and prepared in the memory by executing the code:

```
(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
```

and also some preprocessing to be compatible with my keras model:

```
Train_images = np.expand_dims(train_images,3).astype('float')/255.0
Test_images = np.expand_dims(test_images,3).astype('float')/255.0

Train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_labels)
Test_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(test_labels)
```

Those data are stored in the memory as arrays and there are two option for creating a Dataset object. The first one is simply using `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices`:

```
image = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((Train_images,Train_labels))
```

And input this resulting object to the model.fit():

```
model.fit(x=image,steps_per_epoch=1000)
```

OR input this dataset's iterator by:

```
iterator = image.make_one_shot_iterator()

model.fit(x=iterator,steps_per_epoch=1000)
```

Both of these two options just work fine since the dataset named image here is created using the data in the memory. However, according the the [Importing Data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) here that we may like to avoid doing this because it copies data several times and takes up memory. So another option is creating such a dataset object based on `tf.placeholder` as well as the initialiable iterator:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = [60000,28,28,1])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = [60000,10])
image2 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X,Y))
iterator2 = image.make_initializable_iterator()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(iterator2.initializer,feed_dict={X:Train_images,Y:Train_labels}
  sess.run(iterator2.get_next())
```

This kind of iterator works fine when using `tf.Session()` when fed with the data in the memory and avoids the multiple copies of the data. But I cannot find way to let it work with `keras.model.fit()` since you cannot really call the `iterator.initializer` or feed any data there. Is there a way to use this kind of iterator?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think keras officially supports a case of passing initializable iterators, as you noted, there is no place to provide the placeholders and values mappings.

However a workaround is possible using [keras callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Make sure only tensorflow.keras is imported, don't mix with keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

# example data
x_values = np.random.randn(200, 100).astype(np.float32)
y_labels = np.random.randint(low=0, high=9, size=200)

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    # make datasets from placeholders as in https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#reading_input_data
    # X:
    features_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, x_values.shape, name='features')
    dataset_x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'x': features_placeholder})
    # Y:
    labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], name='labels')
    dataset_y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices({'y': labels_placeholder})

    # compose datasets to make X-Y pairs for training
    dataset0 = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_x, dataset_y))
    dataset0 = dataset0.batch(16).repeat()

    # build model with keras
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(name='x', shape=(x_values.shape[1],))
    mlp1 = layers.Dense(16, name='mlp-1', activation='relu')
    mlp1_out = mlp1(inputs)
    output = layers.Dense(1, name='y', activation='linear')
    output_out = output(mlp1_out)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output_out)
    # The compile step specifies the training configuration.
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001), loss='mse', metrics=['mse'])

    iterator = dataset0.make_initializable_iterator()
    feed_dict = { labels_placeholder: y_labels, features_placeholder: x_values }

    class InitIteratorCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
        """
        Ensures that placeholders in dataset are initialized before each epoch begins
        """

        def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
            sess = K.get_session()
            sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict=feed_dict)


    model.fit(iterator, callbacks=[InitIteratorCallback()],
              epochs=10, steps_per_epoch=300)
```